# Reverse a string with a single loop

Tags: c++

I want to reverse a string by only using a single loop. How can I do it? I tried one simple way but doesn't get the output I wish.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    char a[10];

    cout << " Enter String :";
    cin >> a;

    for(a[i] = '\0'; i > 0; i--)
    {   
        cout << "Reverse string is" << a[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a[i]='\0'` is undefined behaviour. It should be `for(i=9; i>=0; i--)`

Comment: p.s. you never initialize `i` anywhere.

Comment: One of the possible algorithms is swapping string characters: first and last, second and penultimate and so on.

Comment: @dave `i=9`? What if I enter `test` or `abcdefghijklmnopq`?

Comment: `a[i] = '\0'` is wrong in that place, just as `x*x = 4` will not magically set `x` to `2`

Comment: So, `a[i]='\0'` should be `i = a.length() - 1`.

Comment: @mch I was using `i=9` because the array has length 10. Really, this is a good example of why to use `std::string` since it has a `length()` function.

Comment: @dave yes, but in this case it should be `i=8`, `a[9]` is the nul-terminator.

Comment: @mch oh yeah, duh. Forgot about that

Answer (score 5):

Note that you do not initialize your iterator variable `i` and that you could declare the index within the for-statement as you do not need this variable outside the scope of the for-loop. Furthermore, you can also use a `std::string` instead of a char array, this also allows for strings longer than the ten characters as you had specified.

EDIT: I assume that you can use C++17 or newer. From C++17 they finally added the non-member version `std::size` (which I prefer over the member related versions since I read the book effective modern c++ from Scott Meyers). If, for some reason, you cannot use this function, then you can just replace it by the string member function `length`, i.e., `a.length()`.

If you only want to print the reverse of the string you could use something like the following

```
int main()
{
    string a;

    cout << "Enter String: ";
    cin >> a;

    for (int idx = size(a) - 1; idx >= 0; --idx)
      cout << a[idx];
    cout << endl;
}
```

You may also use the built-in reverse function (see [description here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/)). This function actually reverses the string itself.

```
int main()
{
    std::string a;

    std::cout << "Enter String: ";
    std::cin >> a;

    std::reverse(std::begin(a), std::end(a));

    std::cout << a << endl;
}
```

Another option is to manually reverse the string (which doesn't make sense since `std::reverse` is part of the standard library, but as a learning exercise it might be helpful). Note that we only iterate to half the size of the string as otherwise each element is swapped twice, resulting in the original string.

```
int main()
{
  string a;

  cout << "Enter String: ";
  cin >> a;

  for (size_t idx = 0, n = size(a); idx < n / 2; ++idx)
    swap(a[idx], a[n - idx - 1]);
  cout << a << endl;
}
```

Comment: @mch did know that either, see here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size

Comment: Uh, C++17, I learned something, have my +1, but it should be `size(a) - 1`, otherwise the first output would be the nul-terminator.

Comment: @mch `size` and `length` are synonyms I believe. Next, indeed the `-1` was missing, sometimes answering too fast results in unnecessary typos.